# Did Chopper mishandle the candy incident?

Tags: one-piece

During the Punk Hazard arc, some giant children are found, and it comes to light that they're actually research subjects who're given doses on a dangerous and addictive drug. When Chopper sees their violent withdrawal symptoms, he comes up with a plan that doesn't seem medically sound (to me at least, with my very limited knowledge of medicine). Namely, he uses sedatives. First Usopp's sleep gas, and then an injection of his own making. My understanding is that withdrawal can be fatal under some circumstances, so Chopper's adamant decision that they absolutely cannot give the children any more of the drug when they're suffering violent withdrawal seems very misguided. Staving off the withdrawal symptoms until they find a permanent solution seems like a viable solution to me. And I'm not sure how effective sedation would be. Was there a better way? Or is this all medically sound?

For an answer, I'd like either a compilation of medical mistakes made in the treatment of the children, or some proof that this actually was medically sound.

Comment: Well, if there was poison or something similar (in OP world) in the drug, I would also risk it and choose not to give it anymore and handle the withdrawl. It also depends on person's character and Chopper would do anything to save anyone around him.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking the One Piece wiki, there seems to be some similarities between NHC10 and stimulant drugs like methanphetamines.

According to the "Clinical Guidelines for Withdrawal Management and Treatment of Drug Dependence in Closed Settings." published by the World Health Organization, the basis for treatment of withdrawal syndrome in stimulants addiction is symptom-based.

The usual symptons are: agitation, irritability, depression, increased apetite and muscle aches, in the more severe cases they can develop psychosis. These seem compatible with the symptoms presented by the children.

In cases of severe agitation, much like the children presented, it may be necessary to sedate the patients when other behavioural management strategies prove unsuccessful.

The rest of the treatment relies on hydration and multivitamin supplements along with psychological therapy.

So, at least going by our current standards IRL, Chopper seems to have acted in good faith through proper medical treatment.

Source: [Clinical Guidelines for Withdrawal Management and Treatment of Drug Dependence in Closed Settings](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK310652/)

Comment: Good answer. Since it seems methamphetamine is the closest real-world equivalent, this seems relevant : " Unlike withdrawal from other drugs of abuse, like heroin, prescription painkillers, and sedatives, methamphetamine withdrawal is not typically distressing or life-threatening. Withdrawal symptoms may include anxiety, depression, fatigue, meth cravings, and in rare cases, psychosis." https://www.rehabs.com/treatment/methamphetamine/

Comment: And this one: "Withdrawal from crystal meth is most likely not potentially physically damaging unless the individual becomes extremely emotionally unstable and engages in self-harm." https://americanaddictioncenters.org/meth-treatment/withdrawal

Comment: You can put those in your answer if you want. Also, according to the trivia on https://onepiece.fandom.com/wiki/NHC10 NHC10 are the letters of the chemical formula for methamphetamine backwards. That also seems noteworthy.